# jQuery insertbefore

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<table id="StateNames">
<tr>
<td><input name="StateName"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Wyoming</td></tr>
<tr><td>Wisconsin</td></tr>
<tr><td>West Virginia</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to

```
$('input').change(function() {
   var StateName = $(this).val();
   insert <tr><td>StateName</td></tr> before Wyoming
```

Comment: Is this REALLY insert before Wyoming, or is it insert after the Input field row, or is it insert before the first "non" state row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to add the row after the row where the input element is:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var StateName = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('tr').after('<tr><td>'+StateName+'</td></tr>');
});
```

If you explicitly need to insert it before the row that has Wyoming in it, you'd better identify that row somehow – an ID tag would be appropriate:

```
<tr id="wyoming"><td>Wyoming</td></tr>
<tr id="wisconsin"><td>Wisconsin</td></tr>
<tr id="west-wirginia"><td>West Virginia</td></tr>
```

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var StateName = $(this).val();
    // Insert before Wyoming:
    $('#wyoming').before('<tr><td>'+StateName+'</td></tr>');
});
```

You can also use the `:contains()` pseudo class if you don't want to name your rows (it would be faster that way):

```
$("tr:contains('Wyoming')").before('<tr><td>'+StateName+'</td></tr>');
```

Comment: Yes, I was having a hard time explaining what I wanted without being able to point to "there" and saying "right there".
But your assumption was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var newElem = $('<tr></tr>').append($('<td></td>').text(StateName));
$(this).closest('tr').after(newElem);
```

Or:

```
$('tr:contains(Wyoming)').before(newElem);
```